# Unexpected Finder message "This item will be deleted immediately"

Tags: macos, finder, permission, user-account

I made a second user account (`test`, admin privs) and set the permissions of my second hard drive so that this account could read & write. The only thing I changed was the first line and then applying the setting to all enclosed folders.

[image]

Strange things happen.

1. My own user account is not allowed to write to the disk anymore. As I only added permissions, this seems nonsensical to me.
2. When attempting to move an item from that disk to the trash from my own account (not the `test` account), Finder gives me the message

> This item will be deleted immediately.

Which I had never seen before.

Can somebody explain this?

[image]

Comment: Which groups contain your user? The only users so far which can write to disk are test, system and all members of wheel?

Comment: @klanomath How can I find out which groups I belong to?

Comment: `groups <user_name>` or `id <user_name>` should work

Comment: This prints `staff com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 everyone localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin _appstore _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_ftp com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh`. I find it strange that even when I set `read-write` for `everyone` or for my user explicitly, I still have the problem.